# A comparison between a category and its group objects

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C} $ be a complete, cocomplete, and cartesian closed category. Denote by $\mathit{Grp}(\mathbf{C}) $ the category of group objects in $\mathbf{C} $.

> 1) Which of these features does $\mathbf{C} $ share with $\mathit{Grp}(\mathbf{C}) $?
>
> 2) Does the forgetful functor $\mathit{Grp}(\mathbf{C})\hookrightarrow\mathbf{C} $ have a left adjoint?
>
> 3) Is there any reference for a comparison between a category and its group objects?

Comment: The category $ Grp(C) $ may not be a cartesian closed category.  For example, consider the category $ Set $. In this case, $ Grp $ is the category of its group objects, which is not cartesian closed.

Comment: In fact, the only case I can think of where $Grp(C)$ is cartesian closed would be the trivial case where $C = 1$ is the terminal category. Certainly if $C$ is locally presentable, then $Grp(C)$ will be locally presentable too (and in particular complete and cocomplete) and a free group functor will exist. Note also that $Grp(C) \to C$ is an equivalence iff $C$ is additive, so that $C = Grp(C) = Grp(Grp(C)) = Ab(C)$ is the category of abelian group objects in itself.

Comment: @Tim: These facts are very useful for me. It would be great if you mention some references as well.

Comment: @Emptymath This is probably a bit too specific of a question to have an explicit reference. Tim's points mostly follow from very general facts about locally presentable categories, for which Adamek and Rosicky's book with the same title is the canonical reference. The point about $C$ additive is essentially the Eckmann-Hilton argument.

Comment: I am not very familiar with locally presentable categories, although they are interesting for me. I particularly need a reference for the statement that if $ C $ is locally presentable, then $ Grp(C) $ is locally presentable.

Comment: $Grp(C)$ is pointed, so it can't be cartesian closed.